# Increase security on logon

Tags: 7, users, security, authentication-authorization

I am using [Logintoboggan](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7m438jKPLAhVBohQKHcidApcQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Flogintoboggan&usg=AFQjCNFlJ9fapyuqwGYysJI4AsIUiB3kdg) module but by chance by playing around with Wireshark packet sniffing tools I can see all login details and passwords when users login/register on my site!

Is there a way to encrypt login details and/ or add extra security to this module - Are there better secure modules out there?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean, but wouldn't SSL prevent any kind of sniffing on the data sent/received from the website?

Answer (score 1):

#### [Secure Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin) [image]

> For sites that are available via both HTTP and HTTPS, Secure Login
> module ensures that the user login and other forms are submitted
> securely via HTTPS, thus preventing passwords and other private user
> data from being transmitted in the clear. Secure Login module locks
> down not just the user/login page but also any page containing the
> user login block, and any other forms that you configure to be
> secured.
>
> For Drupal 7 and 8, Secure Login module enforces secure authenticated
> session cookies, thus [preventing session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking). For previous
> versions of Drupal, PHP's [session.cookie_secure](https://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure) flag must be enabled
> on the HTTPS site to enforce secure session cookies.

#### [Login Security](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security)

> With Login Security module, a site administrator may protect and
> restrict access by adding access control features to the login forms
> (default login form in /user and the block called "login form block").
> Enabling this module, a site administrator may
>
> limit the number of invalid login attempts before blocking accounts,
> or deny access by IP address, temporarily or permanently. A set of
> notifications by email or Nagios may help the site administrator to
> know when something is happening with the login form of their site:
>
> password and account guessing, bruteforce login attempts or just
> unexpected behaviour with the login operation.